# Looping Through Cells Until I Find the Same String

Tags: vba, excel

I've looked through the previous posts about this problem but can't seem to find a solution. I'm trying to iterate through some lines of code, stopping only when I find a string that matches the one I inputted.

The problem I'm having is that my code only compares the first cell's value. If it doesn't match, it proceeds to exit the loop. In other words, my code isn't looping.

```
Public Function CO_Score(co_name As String) As Integer
Dim row_counter As Long
    row_counter = 3 'Where the CO Scores start
Dim ref_name As String
    ref_name = Worksheets("CO_Scorecard").Cells(row_counter, 2).Value
Dim co_total As Integer
    co_total = Worksheets("CO_Scorecard").Range("R3").Value + 10 'Add some extra buffer
Dim co_found As Integer
    co_found = 1

Do While StrComp(co_name, ref_name, vbTextCompare) = 0
    row_counter = row_counter + 1
    co_found = co_found + 1 '
    ref_name = Worksheets("CO_Scorecard").Cells(row_counter, "M").Value

    If row_counter > co_total Then
        co_found = 0
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

If co_found = 1 Then
    CO_Score = Worksheets("CO_Scorecard").Cells(row_counter, "M").Value
Else
    CO_Score = 0
End If

End Function
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you tried setting some breakpoints and stepping through the code in debug mode? You'll have an easier job doing this than we would without the source data.

Comment: I have indeed. I've isolated it down to the Do Until line, so either I'm not using StrComp correctly, Do Until works differently than I thought, or StrComp and Do Until are incompatible. I'm leaning toward the last option as I've used StrComp in other functions and Do Until seems pretty straightforward

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. I believe you want to compare a `string` value in a column and if the `string` matches then you need to capture that cell.

```
Sub SO3()

Dim InputValue As String
Dim GetCellValue, NumberOfValues As String
Dim i As Integer

InputValue = Worksheets("CO_Scorecard").Range("B1").Value

'number of values in column
NumberOfValues = Worksheets("CO_Scorecard").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 1 To NumberOfValues
GetCellValue = Worksheets("CO_Scorecard").Range("A" & i).Value
If GetCellValue = InputValue Then
MsgBox "Match found in A" & i & " cell"
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`co_found` is just incremented as rowcounter, so you cannot check if the sample has been found. Also, `StrComp` does return `0` only if the strings match.

A (imho) more legible version correcting those two flaws could be:

```
Public Function CO_Score(co_name As String) As Integer
    row_counter = 3
    maxrow = Worksheets("CO_Scorecard").Range("R3").Value
    Do While StrComp(co_name, Worksheets("CO_Scorecard").Cells(row_counter, "M").Value, vbTextCompare) <> 0 _
             And row_counter < maxrow
        row_counter = row_counter + 1
    Loop
    If row_counter < maxrow Then 'found?
        CO_Score = Worksheets("CO_Scorecard").Cells(row_counter, "N").Value ' different column?
    Else
        CO_Score = 0
    End If
End Function
```

*Edit:*
Maybe you want to have a look into the `LOOKUP` and/or `VLOOKUP` functions. Perhaps you actually dont need VBA at all.